# Scaling a normal distribution in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, normal-distribution

I want to plot a histogram for a normal distribution and also plot the corresponding normal distribution over it. There are several examples available online regarding normal distributions with y-axis normalized with `density=True`. In my example, I am trying to form the normal distribution curve without the density type normalization. Perhaps, this could be a mathematical question implicitly but I could not figure out how to "un-normalize" the distribution curve. Following is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu = 1e-3
std = 1.0e-4
nsize = 10000
ymax = 5000

# Generate some data for this demonstration.
data = norm.rvs(mu, std, size=nsize)

# Plot the histogram.
plt.hist(data, bins=20, color='b', edgecolor='black')

# Plot the PDF.
xmin, xmax = [0.5e-3, 1.5e-3] #plt.xlim()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
p = norm.pdf(x, mu, std)                      # something to do with this line
plt.plot(x, p, 'k', linewidth=2)
plt.axvline(mu, linestyle='dashed', color='black')
plt.ylim([0, ymax])
```

This produces the following plot.[image]

As can be seen, the area under the histogram will be equal to 10000 (`nsize`) which is the number of data points. However, it is not so with the "distribution curve". How to obtain the curve match with the histogram?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `plt` returns `hist` that totals to `nsize`. So we can just scale `p`:

```
# Plot the histogram.
hist, bins, _ = plt.hist(data, bins=20, color='b', edgecolor='black')

# Plot the PDF.
xmin, xmax = [0.5e-3, 1.5e-3] #plt.xlim()

# changes here
p = norm.pdf(bins, mu, std)           
plt.plot(bins, p/p.sum() * nsize , 'r', linewidth=2)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: No I do not want to set the `density=True`. That is not the point of this question. I want the curve match the `density=False` case of the histogram

Comment: @SKPS Sorry, I misunderstood the question. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks much. Can you elaborate a bit on the `hist.sum()` part? I know it computes sum of histogram but  which`hist` is used here? `plt.hist` or `numpy`? Can you elaborate the answer with more code please?

Comment: Or if you paste the full code somewhere would be helpful

Comment: Sorry, in my code, `hist, bins, _ = plt.hist(...)`. As said, `hist.sum() == nsize`. So you can just replace it with `nsize`.

Comment: I am really sorry to bother. Something is actually wrong with my `p`. I still have a mismatch with histogram and curve. Can you post the full code in pastebin or here?